# Split MS Access Database takes a long time to open - back end keeps locking and unlocking

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a split MS Access database.  Most of the data is populated through SQL queries run through VBA.  When I first connect to the back end data, it takes a long time and the back end file (.accdc file) locks and unlocks 3 or 4 times.  It's not the same number of locks every time, but this locking and unlocking corresponds to taking a while to open.  When I first open the front end, it does not connect to the back end.  This step is done very quickly.  The first time that I connect to the back end, it can take a while, though.
Any suggestions on things to look into to speed this up, and make it happen more reliably on the first try?  This is a multi-user file and I was not wanting to make any changes to the registry since that would require making that update for everyone in my department.  I'm mostly concerned about it taking a while to open, but thought the locking and unlocking seemed peculiar and might be contributing or a symptom of something else going on.

Comment: multiuser? You should be using a real client-server DB, e.g. mssql, postgres, mysql, etc... not access.

Comment: Not sure why you would see multiple lock/unlock, but years ago we improved performance of our FE/BE by creating variable: 
Public rsAlwaysOpen                 As DAO.Recordset
Global gv_DBS_Server                    As DAO.database 
Then Set rsAlwaysOpen = gv_DBS_Server.OpenRecordset("Some insignificant table")

Comment: Do you see any improvement if you change the file extension of the back-end db file from .accdc to .accdb and then update the front-end links to point to that file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases if you use a persistent connection, then the slow process you note only occurs once at startup. 
This and some other performance tips can be found here:

http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Performance/LinkedDatabase.html

9 out of 10 times, the above will thus fix the "delays" when running the application. You can for testing simply open any linked tables, minimize that table, and now try running your code or startup form - note how the delays are gone.